# How do I convert this subquery to Linq?

Tags: linq

I have following SQL query and trying to convert to LINQ

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ScannedItemId 
                            ORDER BY ScannedDate DESC) AS rn 
     FROM ItemTracking) A  
WHERE 
    A.rn = 1
    AND ScannedLoc = 1
ORDER BY 
    ItemTrackingId DESC
```

This returns item ID that are in the location (`ScannedLoc`) currently.

I'm new to LINQ and finding difficult putting other examples together especially subquery and `Row_Number` function.

Could someone direct me to right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var output = (
    from i in ItemTracking
    group i by i.ScannedItemId into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.ScannedDate).First()
).OrderByDescending(t => t.ItemTrackingId);
```

But I'm not sure what SQL it would translate into.

Comment: Sorry, MS T-SQL. Is it possible to return Anonymous type? I tried .Select new List<string>() {?????}.ToList() but wasn't sure what to put in ???.

Comment: The syntax would be `.Select(t => new { Field = t.Field, Etc = etc }).ToList();`

Comment: I just realized that there is no Where ScannedLoc = 1 clause. If I add it like
 .Where (t => t.ScannedLoc == 1) before second OrderByDesending part, it still returns all rows. First() has to have ScannedLoc column and if it's 1, return it. but not sure where to put it.

Comment: Oh, oops, sorry. Does `First(t => t.ScannedLoc == 1)` work?

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for help!